# Javascript library throws error after Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, definitelytyped

I'm using Dinero.js and the DefinitelyTyped library @types/dinero.js to provide the types.

I use the library like so:

```
import Dinero = require("dinero.js");

export class Money implements Dinero.DineroObject {
    static fromAmount(amount: number): Money {
        console.log("fromAmount")
        console.log(Dinero)

        let money = new Money()
        money.amount = amount
        money.currency = Money.currency
        money.precision = Money.precision

        console.log(Dinero(money).getAmount())

        return money
    }
}

Money.fromAmount(10)
```

When running the script using ts-node, it works fine:

```
fromAmount
{ [Function: Dinero]
  defaultAmount: 0,
  defaultCurrency: 'ZAR',
  defaultPrecision: 2,
  globalLocale: 'en-ZA',
  globalFormat: '$0,0.00',
  globalRoundingMode: 'HALF_EVEN',
  globalFormatRoundingMode: 'HALF_AWAY_FROM_ZERO',
  globalExchangeRatesApi:
   { endpoint: undefined,
     headers: undefined,
     propertyPath: undefined },
  normalizePrecision: [Function: normalizePrecision],
  minimum: [Function: minimum],
  maximum: [Function: maximum] }
10
```

However, after packaging it with Webpack, I get:

```
fromAmount
Object [Module] {
  default:
   { [Function: Dinero]
     defaultAmount: 0,
     defaultCurrency: 'USD',
     defaultPrecision: 2,
     globalLocale: 'en-US',
     globalFormat: '$0,0.00',
     globalRoundingMode: 'HALF_EVEN',
     globalFormatRoundingMode: 'HALF_AWAY_FROM_ZERO',
     globalExchangeRatesApi:
      { endpoint: undefined,
        headers: undefined,
        propertyPath: undefined },
     normalizePrecision: [Function: normalizePrecision],
     minimum: [Function: minimum],
     maximum: [Function: maximum] },
  defaultCurrency: 'ZAR',
  defaultPrecision: 2,
  globalLocale: 'en-ZA' }
webpack:///./src/models/*.ts?:131
        console.log(Dinero(money).getAmount());
                    ^

TypeError: Dinero is not a function
    at Function.fromAmount (webpack:///./src/models/userscan.ts?:131:21)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/models/transaction.ts?:24:58)
    at Object../src/models/transaction.ts (/home/**/.serverless/**/*.js:18580:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/**/.serverless/**/src/*.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/models/*.ts?:25:23)
    at Object../src/models/payout.ts (/home/**/.serverless/**/*.js:18544:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/**/.serverless/**/*.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/models/scan.ts?:29:18)
    at Object../src/models/scan.ts (/home/**/.serverless/**/*.js:18556:1)
```

Please explain why webpack changes the definition of Dinero and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This import seems very weird to me, it's half way between es6 import and commonJS. You might want to pick one or the other but not mix them up.

`import Dinero = require("dinero.js")`

I guess webpack is going a little bit crazy with that.
Try to require it with the canonical commonjs method and then if it works go with the es6 import. Do not use `.js` at the end, see below.

```
const Dinero = require("dinero")
```

If the fix above doesn't work you might have to share your webpack config. There might be something wrong in the webpack loader configuration (ex. Babel).